# Why was this comment removed?

Tags: discussion, comments

[Should one use first or third person terminology when discussing one's character?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/375278/should-one-use-first-or-third-person-terminology-when-discussing-ones-character)

Seems like such a mundane thing but I'm mostly curious, why was my comment here removed? I voted to close as it's definitely off topic, but expressing my interest in an answer and directing to Reddit doesn't seem like a bad thing, and I've definitely seen this done plenty of times (see: every game identification thread ever).

I'm not in bigtime with the rule changes and such on this site anymore, but did something wildly change?

Comment: If you click the flag comment button, one of the reasons to flag is "This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post." - so technically if your comment becomes outdated, it does stand to be deleted.  I've seen in the past with various mods comment flagging being handled differently.  Honestly I just stay away from it unless a comment is blatantly in violation of SE rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the comment because it served its purpose. I didn't see any reason to keep it around after the question was closed.

This is a fairly borderline case, however, so after thinking about it some more I've gone ahead and undeleted the comment.

Comment: Is that just your judgement call, or is that a rule for the site? It's not a huge deal but in an effort not to turn users off to our site, I try to explain a rule in a gentle way and to offer a potential other solution or place to ask. Personally if I asked a question that busted a rule, and it was closed out without any sort of comment on it, that would likely turn me off to the site in general. I don't necessarily agree with deleting the comment.

Comment: Deleting comments after they're no longer relevant is standard practice network-wide. Mentioning the reason to close a question is fairly redundant after the question is closed. There is some slight value in keeping the comment about asking elsewhere, though - not necessarily for the site, but for the asker - so I've undeleted the comment.